# Perl : string of variable within a variable

Tags: string, perl, variables

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:
I want to "defined" a name for the input and then when it's taken into a function, only then it will substitute all the 3 variables.

```
$place_holder = 'f${file_case}_lalal_${subcase}_${test}';
```

.... somewhere else in another function:

read file containing 3 set of numbers on each line that represents the $file_case, $subcase, $test

```
while(<IN>){
   ($file_case, $subcase, $tset) = split;
   $input = $place_holder    #### line #3 here needs to fix
   print " $input \n";
}
```

Unfortunately, it prints out f${file_case}*lalal*${subcase}_${test} for every single line. I want those variables to be substituted. How do I do that, how 
do I change line #3 to be able to output as i wanted ? I don't want to defined the input name in the subroutine, it has to be in the main.

Comment: Note: interpolation only happens in double-quoted strings, but your example is single-quoted.

Comment: I know. the $place_holder acts like a function at that time, the 3 variables are NOT known yet. therefore NOT to be substituted.  But the $place_holder needs to be in a place where user can easily change to what they like. The rest of the substitution are hidden in functions where user do not need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using subroutines for example, if that satisfies your criteria

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $place_holder = sub {
    my ($file_case, $subcase, $test) = @_;    
    return "f${file_case}_lalal_${subcase}_${test}";
}

# ...

while (<IN>) { 
    my ($file_case, $subcase, $tset) = split;
    #
    #  Code to validate input
    #
    my $input = $place_holder->($file_case, $subcase, $tset);
    print "$input\n";
}
```

I've used [code reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) with an [anonymous subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) in anticipation of uses that may benefit from it, but for the specified task alone you can use a normal subroutine as well.

Note that you have `$test` and `$tset`, which doesn't affect the above but may be typos.

Comment: Thank you. That certainly is one way to make it work elegantly.

Comment: @OngBengSeong  Thank you -- the points I had in mind are that it separates phases of processing for easier management (for example, precise variable names don't matter), the coderef can be passed around as needed -- and it avoids `eval`-ing user input.

Comment: what if I have 12 different set of filenames and i go with subroutine style
my $file_name = sub{
}

Comment: @OngBengSeong  You mean this whole thing processes a file and it needs to be done for 12 different files?  You just put it all in a loop over those filenames. So for each filename the `my $place_holder = sub { ... };` is defined, (then you open the file), then you read from it doing what is in `while (<IN>)`.  If it is something more involved it may be a good separate question

Comment: Hi Zdim, you'll be happy to know I know end up using a subroutine for the name like your suggestion. I've actually tried both and after a few days, change to the subroutine version which I think is still more elegant and organized. Thank you again !!

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`String::Interpolate`](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/String-Interpolate-0.32/lib/String/Interpolate.pm) module, like this

```
use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';

my $place_holder = 'f${file_case}_lalal_${subcase}_${test}';


while ( <IN> ) {
    my ($file_case, $subcase, $test) = split;

    my $input = interpolate($place_holder);
    print "$input\n";
}
```

The module gives access to Perl's built-in C code that performs double-quote interpolation, so it is generally fast and accurate

Answer (score 0):

A while after I posted, I found a way to do it.

in the ## line 3, do this:

($input = $place_holder) =~ s/(\${w+})/$1/eeg;

and everything works. Yes the above tset is a typo, meant to be test. Thank for everybody's response.

Comment: This is what I warned about initially -- it evaluates user input. That is inherently dangerous. I don't mean only for possible bad intent, but mere typos or wrong data can get evaluated so to wreak havoc on your code. Note that this `eval`-uates content of `$1` as _arbitrary Perl code_. (Which is why I didn't mention it in my answer, despite referring to it in an early comment.) I strongly suggest not doing this, if there is another way.

Comment: By "_user input_" in my previous comment, I meant also input from data. We never can be sure what is in a "data" file. I would add a comment that data would need to be verified extensively before `/ee`, which involves `eval`.

Comment: It is good that you found a working solution yourself and posted it (btw, I didn't downvote it).

Answer (score -1):

Try **eval** `while(<IN>){ ($file_case, $subcase, $tset) = split; $input = eval $place_holder #### line #3 here needs to fix print " $input \n"; }`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that before and it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: what error you got? If you didn't pick it, it's same as your solution. So it should work.